# Flutter - How to trigger an animation inside a child widget from its parent widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this slightly complex flow of providers and widgets, codes will be at the very bottom of this post

Theres 2 things I have done:

1. A heartbeat timer that runs every few seconds (and I want to trigger an animation on every heartbeat), it is located at the root of the widgets' initState function (MainPage)
2. I have made a provider and some functions so that I wont have to use navigation to navigate pages, instead, I use providers to call different widgets as pages when needed, so they are called and initialized inside the build function of (MainPage)

My goal is to add an animation (or to put it simpler, trigger a function) inside one of the widgets (HomePage) and run the animation everytime the heartbeat function runs, however, the heartbeat function is created and ran before the providers or the widgets are even initialized, so i dont know how to get access to the widgets (as I have tried using GlobalKey before).

Please feel free to comment questions and I'll try to ask and provide more info.

Code:

main(login) (not related, i put it here incase you need to run it):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:loginpage/pages/mainPage.dart';
import 'pages/mainPage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  //default password and username
  final String username = "MASTER";
  final String password = "";

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  bool showTitle = true;
  double titleOpacity = 1.0;
  List<Widget> widgetList = [];
  bool isLoginValid = true;
  final usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  List<Widget> initWidgetList() {
    return <Widget>[
      const SizedBox(
        height: 200,
      ),
      AnimatedOpacity(
        child: Text(
          "Bruh",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60, color: Colors.orange[600]),
        ),
        //set initial state
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        opacity: titleOpacity,
      ),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 80,
      ),
      Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Container(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  errorText: isLoginValid ? null : "Username not match",
                  helperText: "",
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                  hintText: 'Username',
                ),
                inputFormatters: [
                  UpperCaseTextFormatter(),
                ],
                controller: usernameController,
              ),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    errorText: isLoginValid ? null : "Password not match",
                    helperText: "",
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                    hintText: 'Password'),
                controller: passwordController,
              ),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text(
                'Forgot Password?',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16),
              ),
              onPressed: null,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                //To Home Page
                isLoginValid = loginValidation(
                    usernameController.text, passwordController.text);
                if (isLoginValid) {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()));
                } else {
                  setState(() {});
                }
              },
              child: Text(
                'Login',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
              ),
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.purple[900],
                  shape: StadiumBorder(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 80, right: 80, top: 10, bottom: 10)),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text(
                'Sign Up',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple[900], fontSize: 24),
              ),
              onPressed: () => setState(() {
                titleOpacity = showTitle ? 0 : 1;
                showTitle = showTitle ? false : true;
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  bool loginValidation(username, password) {
    // if (username != widget.username) {
    //   return false;
    // }
    // if (password != widget.password) {
    //   return false;
    // }
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    widgetList = initWidgetList();
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
          // in the middle of the parent.
          child: Column(children: widgetList),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple[
          900], // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class UpperCaseTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: newValue.text.toUpperCase(),
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }
}
```

mainPage:

```
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loginpage/main.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '/providers/globalProvider.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => MainPageState();
}

class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  LoginPage loginPage = LoginPage();
  String data =
      '[{"Account code ":"32100","Account Name":"Taxation () - sub","Type":"P","Nature":"O","OI":"N","Closed":"N","RowKey":"32100"}]';
  bool loggedIn = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    startHeartBeat();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<MainInfoProvider>(
            create: (_) => MainInfoProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeProvider>(create: (_) => ThemeProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<CheckBoxProvider>(
            create: (_) => CheckBoxProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<TreeViewProvider>(
            create: (_) => TreeViewProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<DraggableProvider>(
            create: (_) => DraggableProvider()),
      ],
      child: Consumer5<MainInfoProvider, ThemeProvider, CheckBoxProvider,
          TreeViewProvider, DraggableProvider>(
        builder: (context, mainInfoProvider, themeProvider, checkBoxProvider,
            treeViewProvider, draggableProvider, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            theme: themeProvider.getTheme(),
            home: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text(
                    mainInfoProvider.titleName,
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  leading: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        //Back to Login Page only when its at home page
                        mainInfoProvider.goBack();
                        if (mainInfoProvider.backToLogin) {
                          loggedIn = false;
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
                        }
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                      )
                      // Image.asset('assets/images/backbtn.png'),
                      ),
                  actions: mainInfoProvider.actionList,
                ),
                body: mainInfoProvider.currentPage),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  //set timer, once timer is up, trigger animation (provider)
  //rmb to check if it is still home page
  Future<void> startHeartBeat() async {
    bool heartBeat = true;
    while (heartBeat) {
      print('heartBeat: $heartBeat');
      //trigger animation somehow
      heartBeat = false;
      heartBeat = await updateHeartBeat();
    }
  }

  Future<bool> updateHeartBeat() {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      if (!loggedIn) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

home(one of the widget pages, remove the others as they are not related):

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loginpage/main.dart';
import 'package:loginpage/pages/autoScroll.dart';
import 'package:loginpage/pages/tabPage.dart';
import 'package:loginpage/pages/mobileList.dart';
import 'package:loginpage/pages/treeView.dart';
import 'package:loginpage/pages/draggable.dart';
import 'package:loginpage/providers/globalProvider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  LoginPage loginPage = LoginPage();
  String data =
      '[{"Account code ":"32100","Account Name":"Taxation (HK) - sub","Type":"P","Nature":"O","OI":"N","Closed":"N","RowKey":"32100"}]';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MainInfoProvider mainInfoProvider = context.watch<MainInfoProvider>();
    ThemeProvider themeProvider = context.watch<ThemeProvider>();
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 30),
              Text('This is the Home Page'),
// add animation here that change the text like a pulse
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text(loginPage.username),
              SizedBox(height: 20)
                ],
              )

              //Tab Page
              // Container(
              //   child: tabPage,
              // ),
              // TextButton(
              //     onPressed: () {
              //       Navigator.push(
              //           context,
              //           MaterialPageRoute(
              //               builder: (context) => MobileList(data: data)));
              //     },
              //     child: Text("Mobile List")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            themeProvider.changeTheme();
            // tabPage!.tabindex == tabPage!.tabNum - 1
            //     ? tabPage!.tabindex = 0
            //     : tabPage!.tabindex += 1;
            // //callback method
            // //GlobalKey method
            // //Set Global Key
            // (tabPage!.key as GlobalKey<TabPageState>) //Casting
            //     .currentState
            //     ?.tabSetState();
            // // tabPageKey.currentState?.tabSetState();

            // (tabPage!.key as GlobalKey<TabPageState>)
            //     .currentState!
            //     .scrollToOffset(100, Duration(milliseconds: 200));
          },
          child: Icon(
            themeProvider.floatingActionIcon,
            color: themeProvider.getTheme().scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

globalProviders(remove the unrelated ones):

```
import 'package:loginpage/pages/home.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:loginpage/storageManager.dart';

class MainInfoProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Widget _currentPage = HomePage();
  String _titleName = "Home Page";
  List<Widget> _actionList = [];
  List<PageInfo> _pageList = [];
  bool _backToLogin = false;

  String get titleName => _titleName;
  Widget get currentPage => _currentPage;
  List<Widget> get actionList => _actionList;
  List<PageInfo> get pageList => _pageList;
  bool get backToLogin => _backToLogin;

  void goToPage(String titleName, Widget page,
      [List<Widget> actionList = const [], bool goBack = false]) {
    this._currentPage = page;
    this._titleName = titleName;
    this._actionList = actionList;

    PageInfo pageInfo = PageInfo();
    pageInfo.page = page;
    pageInfo.titleName = titleName;
    pageInfo.actionList = actionList;
    if (goBack == false) {
      this._pageList.add(pageInfo);
    }
    this._backToLogin = false;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void goBack() {
    //To Login Page
    if (this._pageList.length == 0) {
      this._backToLogin = true;
    } else {
      this._pageList.removeLast();
      //To Home Page
      if (this._pageList.length == 0) {
        goToPage("Home Page", HomePage(), [], true);
      } else {
        goToPage(
            this._pageList[this._pageList.length - 1].titleName,
            this._pageList[this._pageList.length - 1].page,
            this._pageList[this._pageList.length - 1].actionList,
            true);
      }
    }
  }
}

class PageInfo {
  Widget page = Container();
  String titleName = "";
  List<Widget> actionList = [];
}

class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String? _theme;

  IconData _floatingActionIcon = Icons.light_mode_outlined;

  IconData get floatingActionIcon => _floatingActionIcon;

  final lightTheme = ThemeData(
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black)),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      textTheme: TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
      textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: ButtonStyle(
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey[200]),
              shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black),
              textStyle:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(color: Colors.black)))),
      floatingActionButtonTheme:
          FloatingActionButtonThemeData(backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850]));

  final darkTheme = ThemeData(
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white)),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
      textTheme: TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: ButtonStyle(
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey[850]),
              shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black),
              textStyle:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(color: Colors.white)))),
      floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      ));

  ThemeData getTheme() => _theme == "light" ? lightTheme : darkTheme;
  String? get theme => _theme;

  ThemeProvider() {
    StorageManager.readData('theme').then((value) {
      _theme = value ?? "light";
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  void changeTheme() {
    _theme = _theme == "light" ? "dark" : "light";
    //Change Icons
    _floatingActionIcon = _theme == "light"
        ? Icons.light_mode_outlined
        : Icons.dark_mode_outlined;
    StorageManager.saveData("theme", _theme);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

StoreManager (just a session storage):

```
class StorageManager {
  //save data as a key-value pair
  static void saveData(String key, dynamic value) async {
    //get the storage
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //check the type of the value
    if (value is int) {
      prefs.setInt(key, value);
    } else if (value is String) {
      prefs.setString(key, value);
    } else if (value is bool) {
      prefs.setBool(key, value);
    } else {
      print("Invalid Type");
    }
  }

  static Future<dynamic> readData(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    dynamic obj = prefs.get(key);
    return obj;
  }

  static Future<bool> deleteData(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.remove(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's always encouraged to post code in your question, but not the whole project :D that actually confuses the people who are trying to help you here.

Comment: GlobalKey will be definitely a valid solution, if you somehow have any difficulties using it, you can try eventbus https://pub.dev/packages/event_bus